# How to log information in the browser console from an ASP.NET Core 7 application? Problems with Deployed app on Azure

Tags: asp.net

I am having issues with my cloud deployment on Azure, and I am trying to figure out the debugging process.

To put it simply, my web app deployed on Azure does not behave the same way it does locally when I build the app. It looks for redirections that do not exist in the code, etc...

To try to debug this, I've been trying to log some information going through my controllers and repositories. When locally, I have set up Serilog to create logs, and they display in the output console no problems.

Now, I would like to find a way to log some information and send it to the browser console, but have not found a way yet (from my backend code, in my controller).
I found the Azure Log Stream console not very helpful, or at least, all the logs created do not figure in the Azure console. Even setting it up at as "Verbose".

Is there way to create some logs on my backend to show in the browser's console? Or a way to show my logs in the Azure's log stream maybe?

Thank you,

Comment: If you log stuff using ILogger<T> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line), you could access the logs in Azure, for example in LogStream.

Comment: Browser console isn't a good place for server side logs. That ties it to browser functionality, makes it subject to page refreshes, how do you know which connection to send the logs to etc. Instead, you can use LogStream, Application Insights, or any number of 3rd party tools that can receive your log data. It just takes some research from you to figure out which tool gives you the right features at the right price.

Comment: LogStream does not show the logs I am putting in through ILogger<T>. 
However, I was able to find the right console in Azure where my logs would be displayed. I could  find those logs in the App Service Editor in the Azure menu.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct answer to my question of showing logs in the browser console, but a solution nonetheless because it allows to keep track of the logs and see the logs published on the Azure platform, and thus, debug the app.

In the Azure portal, you'll find "App Service Editor" in the "Development Tools" category. Once in this editor, you'll have access to your logs.